# How to take screenshot in uipath forms?

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am not able to take a screenshot of the form using a button. The code for the screenshot is written in the "Do" sequence of uipath forms but for some reason, the execution is not entering the Do sequence.

There is a multi-assign activity before the declaration of form designer in which 4 variables are declared and assigned to base 64 images. These variables are used in the HTML component of uipath forms.

I need to take the screenshot of these images only. If I disable the multi-assign activity, the code is working fine for me as I am able to take the screenshot but as soon as I enable the multi-assign activity, the execution is not entering the "Do" sequence.

Comment: You want to show the process? And are the variables correctly initialized?

Comment: No, i want to take the screenshot of the forms and store it in a path. Yes, all the variables are correctly initialized.

Comment: What is your screenshot of a form?

Comment: The form which will be displayed during the run. There is an html component declared inside the form which will display some images. I need to take the screenshot of those images using a button. I had also declared a button component of type boolean.